# how to setup k3s between 2 raspberry pis over an ethernet cable

Tags: kubernetes

good day everyone, i am new to k3s and was trying to setup a k3s master and a k3s worker on two raspberry pis with the goal of connecting both via Ethernet cable (not if it is possible)
k3s-master-01 (Raspberry Pi 4B)
k3s-worker-01 (Raspberry Pi 3B+)
Both of them are connected via Ethernet cable on their ethernet ports, eth0 interface. (169.254.xxx.xxx)

Running k3s server command:

```
k3s --debug server --disable coredns --disable traefik --disable servicelb --write-kubeconfig-mode 644 --node-name k3s-master-01 --node-external-ip 169.254.xxx.xxx
```

**First Error**: i got this error here:

```
FATA[0000] unable to select an IP from default routes.
```

route table:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
```

But then, after i enable wlan0 (ifconfig wlan0 up), I am able to run the server command which i then proceed to run the agent command:

```
k3s --debug agent --server https://169.254.xxx.xxx:6443 --token myservertoken --node-ip 169.254.yyy.yyy  --node-name k3s-worker-01
```

I am to see the two nodes k3s-worker-01 and k3s-master-01 in Ready Status.
However, i am seeing an error on worker node log.

**Second Error** on worker node:

```
ERRO[0006] Failed to connect to proxy. Empty dialer response  error="dial tcp 192.168.10.105:6443: connect: no route to host"
ERRO[0006] Remotedialer proxy error                      error="dial tcp 192.168.10.105:6443: connect: no route to host"
```

I am not sure why agent connects to host via wlan0 (192.168.xxx.xxx) instead of the eth0 (169.254.xxx.xxx).

Is there something i had made a mistake in setting up k3s or have i missed out settings on my routing tables?

Would glad to share more information as well.
thanks in advance

Comment: 169.254.xxx.xxx suggests you don't have a working DHCP server is that intentional?  It also suggests you have not properly defined a route to `192.168.10.105`

Comment: @Ramhound sorry for the late reply, I have now used an external router which also serves as an external DHCP server which is able to solve my problems. But, i tried to look for information regarding k3s and having a DHCP server as requirement but can't figure the reason.